# scope not working for omniauth-facebook gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, permissions, scope, omniauth

I am using the `omniauth-facebook` gem (version 1.4.1) in a Rails 3.2.11 app. My code in config/initializers/omniauth.rb looks like

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 'app_id', 'app_secret', scope: 'email, publish_stream', 
end
```

yet when authenticating with Facebook it still only asks for and assigns email (which is default in `omniauth-facebook`). Is `scope` no longer in use?

I have been following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/361-facebook-graph-api) Railscast.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you restart your rails server after updating the config file? Are you using the Koala gem or similar gems for FB API access?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Koala to access the Facebook API. I did restart the server...I ended up finding a solution. Facebook sets their apps to return a "code" instead of a "token" by default. Once I changed that to token, it started to work.

Comment: May I ask you about changing "code" to "token"? What FB api to do that?